# Issues with Mura Custom form validation

Tags: coldfusion, mura

I have created a custom file in `displayobjects` in Mura called myform.cfm and added the form code in that form. I am using jQuery Validator to validate the form using the data required attributes of jQuery but it is always skipping the validation. Here is my code:

```
Mura(function(m) {
    window.customFormValidation = function(theform) {
        theform.validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                Mura.submitForm(theform);
                return false;
            }
        });
        // let Mura process the form now
        //Mura.submitForm(theform);
        //return false;
    }
});
```

It is always failing:

I added the following in my form:

```
<form id="contact_form_request" name="contact_form_request" 
      data-autowire=true action="" method="post" 
      onsubmit="window.customFormValidation(this);return false;" novalidate>
```

Comment: And what do your form fields look like?  Are there any errors being shown in the browser's console window (within dev tools)?

Comment: no error, it just submits

Comment: are you able to access window.customFormValidation in the console after page load?